# PHP Mcrypt error: Cannot open source device

Tags: php, mcrypt

I downgraded to `PHP 5.2.8` from `PHP 5.4.2` for a reason, I enabled the `mcrypt` extension, but when I run the function `mcrypt_create_iv ($size, MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM)`, it doesn't execute properly, and I get the following warning

```
Warning: mcrypt_create_iv() [function.mcrypt-create-iv]:Cannot open source device
```

Please how do I fix this issue? Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

The issue occurred because `MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM` was only supported on Windows as from `PHP version 5.3.0`, that is why it was working well until the downgrade.

I changed to `MCRYPT_RAND` which worked on previous versions and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

> Locate the file includes/CryptRandom.php. Find the following line
>   (probably around line 285): $iv = mcrypt_create_iv( $rem,
>   MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM ); Change it to: $iv = mcrypt_create_iv( $rem,
>   MCRYPT_RAND );

[Source](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Thread%3aProject%3aSupport_desk/mcrypt_create_iv%28%29_function.mcrypt-create-iv_%3a_Cannot_open_source_device)

Comment: Chris thanks, I saw that link before posting this question, but I couldn't locate that file. I use wamp.

Answer (score 0):

Check the device file (if Linux):

```
/dev/random
```